# Reportlab \ Catalina Installation failure : ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

Context: macOS Catalina:  `pip3 install marisol` returns:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: reportlab
  Building wheel for reportlab (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/user/pyViutualEnv/marisol/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/pip-install-4sqwyoby/reportlab_8b45a6fc8e1f41dda74996813181243c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/pip-install-4sqwyoby/reportlab_8b45a6fc8e1f41dda74996813181243c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s_xiwi84
       cwd: /private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/pip-install-4sqwyoby/reportlab_8b45a6fc8e1f41dda74996813181243c/
```

Complete return: https://pastebin.com/raw/2HvMLVVt

What exactly is the problem and the remedy?

Update: macOS High Sierra:  `pip3 install marisol` successfully installed and returned no errors

Comment: marisol shows support till Python 3.6., Are you sure it will work on 3.9 ?

Comment: @Kris I do not know.   Is there a test that can be performed to confidently confirm that 3.9 is the problem?